# Error en symfony al acceder getParameter

Tags: symfony3

Estoy inmerso en un proyecto en symfony y estoy haciendo unas pruebas con diferentes bundles.

En el primer bundle **CatalogBundle** , se encarga de gestionar dos entidades, `Producto` y `Proveedor` con su respectivo formulario y demás. Cuando añado un proveedor, guardo su imagen en un directorio. En este bundle añado un evento que se ha eliminado un proveedor `supplier_deleted`.

En el segundo bundle **FileManagerBundle**, tiene un event listener que se encarga de escuchar si hay un evento `supplier_deleted`. Si es así, elimina la imagen asociada.

Cuando intento hacerlo, symfony me devuelve el error

> Call to a member function getParameter() on null

Este es el código de **FileManagerBundleController**

```
namespace FileManagerBundle\Controller;

use Symfony\Bundle\FrameworkBundle\Controller\Controller;

class FileManagerController extends Controller
{

    public function deleteSupplierImage (Supplier $supplier)
    {
        $supplierImage = $supplier->getLogo();
        unlink($this->getParameter('kernel.root_dir').'/../web/uploads/suppliers/'.$supplierImage);
    }
}
```

**FileManagerBundle\Resources\config\services.yml**

```
services:
    FileManagerBundle.FileManagerController:
        class: FileManagerBundle\Controller\FileManagerController
    FileManagerBundle.delete_supplier_image_event_listener:
        class: FileManagerBundle\EventListener\DeleteSupplierImageEventListener
        arguments:
            - "@FileManagerBundle.FileManagerController"
        tags:
            - { name: kernel.event_listener, event: supplier_deleted, method: deleteSupplierImage }
```

**FileManagerExtension.php**

```
namespace FileManagerBundle\DependencyInjection;

use Symfony\Component\DependencyInjection\Extension\Extension;
use Symfony\Component\DependencyInjection\ContainerBuilder;
use Symfony\Component\DependencyInjection\Loader\YamlFileLoader;
use Symfony\Component\Config\FileLocator;

class FileManagerExtension extends Extension
{
    public function load(array $configs, ContainerBuilder $container)
    {
        $loader = new YamlFileLoader(
            $container,
            new FileLocator(__DIR__.'/../Resources/config/')
        );
        $loader->load('services.yml');
    }
}
```

Alguna idea de lo que puede estar mal?

Answer (score 0):

Porque estás inyectando el controlador?
El controlador no se inyecta, y en caso que quisieras hacerlo por alguna razón (primero deberías plantearte la arquitectura), no por el hecho de extender Controller de FrameworkBundle significa que $this->getParameter deba funcionar.

$this->getParameter solo funciona cuando estás en un controlador y no lo has definido como servicio. En caso que lo definas como servicio, debes inyectar tu manualmente el container "@service_container" con el setter "setContainer".

Sino, claro, no encuentra "container".

Insisto, inyectar el controlador no tiene ningún sentido.

Comment: Gracias!!! Ahora parece que tiene sentido!

Answer (score 0):

En symfony 3.3 esta depreciado el uso de 'kernel.root_dir' y se debe emplear el siguiente código

```
$this->getContainer()->getParameter('kernel.project_dir')
```

Pienso que te falla por la falta del ->getContainer()